# How to Combine two pivot tables when both the tables are combined by inner Join function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Tag

SELECT TOP (1000) [System_Order_Id]
  ,[Batch_No]
  ,[Material_Code]
  ,[Set_Weight]
  ,[Actual_Weight]
  FROM [master].[dbo].[Consumption_Report]
```

|  | Batch No | System Id | Material Code | Set Weight | Actual Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Mat01 | 100 | 99 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | Mat02 | 50 | 55 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | Mat03 | 80 | 35 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | Mat04 | 40 | 20 |

```
SELECT TOP (1000)[Batch_End_TimeStamp]
  ,[Machine_Code]
  , [User_Order_Id]
  ,[Batch_No]
  ,[Recipe_Code]
  ,[Cycle_Time]
  ,[System_Mode]
  FROM [master].[dbo].[Batch_Report]
```

|  | System Id | Batch No | Machine_Code | Recipe_Code | Cycle_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 23 | AA01 | 532 |

```
My Code:

WITH Consumption_Report AS (
SELECT
  t1.Material_Code,
  t1.Set_Weight,
  t2.Batch_End_TimeStamp, 
  t2.Machine_Code, 
  t2.User_Order_Id, 
  t2.Recipe_Code, 
  t2.Cycle_Time   
  FROM
  dbo.Consumption_Report t1
  INNER JOIN  dbo.Batch_Report t2 ON t2.Batch_No = t1.Batch_No
)

  SELECT *
FROM Consumption_Report
PIVOT (AVG(Set_Weight) FOR Material_Code IN (Mat01,Mat02,Mat03,Mat04)) P


I want output like this:
```

|  | Batch No | System Id | Machine_Code | Recipe_Code | Cycle_Time | Mat 01 Set Weight | Mat 01 Actual Weight | Mat 02 Set Weight | Mat 02 Actual Weight | Mat 03 Set Weight | Mat 03 Actual Weight | Mat 04 Set Weight | Mat 04 Actual Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 23 | AA01 | 532 | 100 | 99 | 50 | 55 | 80 | 35 | 40 | 20 |

Comment: What database provider?

Comment: Please explain the logic for what you want to accomplish.  And provide a database tag.

Comment: Database provider is SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what the second table has to do with anything.  Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select Id, Batch_No, System_Id,
       max(case when Material_Code = 'Mat01' then set_weight end) as mat01_set_weight,
       max(case when Material_Code = 'Mat01' then actual_weight end) as mat01_actual_weight,
       max(case when Material_Code = 'Mat02' then set_weight end) as mat02_set_weight,
       max(case when Material_Code = 'Mat02' then actual_weight end) as mat02_actual_weight,
       max(case when Material_Code = 'Mat03' then set_weight end) as mat03_set_weight,
       max(case when Material_Code = 'Mat03' then actual_weight end) as mat03_actual_weight,
       max(case when Material_Code = 'Mat04' then set_weight end) as mat04_set_weight,
       max(case when Material_Code = 'Mat04' then actual_weight end) as mat04_actual_weight
from Consumption_Report
group by Id, Batch_No, System_Id;
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Batch_Report
INNER JOIN (
select Batch_No,
sum(case when Material_Code = 'Mat01' then Set_Weight else 0 end) as Mat01,
sum(case when Material_Code = 'Mat01' then Actual_Weight else 0 end) as 
Mat01_Act,
sum(case when Material_Code = 'Mat02' then Set_Weight else 0 end) as Mat02,
sum(case when Material_Code = 'Mat02' then Actual_Weight else 0 end) as 
Mat02_Act,
sum(case when Material_Code = 'Mat03' then Set_Weight else 0 end) as Mat03,
sum(case when Material_Code = 'Mat03' then Actual_Weight else 0 end) as 
Mat03_Act,
sum(case when Material_Code = 'Mat04' then Set_Weight else 0 end) as Mat04,
sum(case when Material_Code = 'Mat04' then Actual_Weight else 0 end) as Mat04_Act      
from Consumption_Report
group by Batch_No) Consumption_Report
ON Batch_Report.Batch_No = Consumption_Report.Batch_No;
```